# show attributes in filter that related with configurable product

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

In my store i have products with 2 main attributes : color and size.

In product listing page i display each color of product, to do so i gave visibility for first simple product of each color (the smallest size) in configurable product.

Thats works fine for me, the only problem i have is with the size attribute in filters section, because in product listing only one size appear, i don't have other sizes as filter option that are related to the configurable product, is there a way to display those sizes ?

Answer (score 0):

What I have understand from your problem description is that, you want to show all color variations of same product in product list page, while the size attribute should be selected by the user.

For that, suppose you have product A and Product B, which are indeed the same product but with color variation, say red and yellow. What you have to do now is create a configurable product whose color is set to red (only red, don't add other color variations) and set size attribute as configurable options. (This is our product A). Similarly you need to create another configurable product whose color set to yellow and set size attribute as configurable option (Product B). Now display product A and Product B in product list page.

Note: For this you need 4 simple product

```
   simple product 1 
        - color : red
        - size : 1
                             => These constitute product A
   simple product 2 
        - color : red
        - size : 2



   simple product 3 
        - color : yellow
        - size : 1
                            => These two constitute prodcut B
   simple product 4 
        - color : yellow
        - size : 2
```

and now your configurabe products

```
   configurable product A
        - COLOR : RED
        - configured with : simple product 1
                            simple product 2

  configurable product B
        - COLOR : YELLOW
        - configured with : simple product 3
                            simple product 4
```

Showing product A and product B in product list page will fix your problem.

Good Luck

Comment: I forget to mention that i need the color variation in the same configuration product because the client want the user have an option to change a color when he visiting the product page